# Guice : conditionally instantiate 1 concrete implementation of an interface (among many) at runtime

Tags: guice, guice-3

I am pretty new to Guice and have been trying to see if my problem is solvable with Guice. I have a main Driver class which looks like this :

```
public class Driver{
  execute(){
    Manager m = injector.getInstance(Manager.class);
  }
}

public class Manager{

  private List<IExecutor> executors;

  @Inject
  public Manager(IExecutorWrapper executor){
    this.executors = executor.getExecutors();
  }

  public List<IExecutor> getExecutors() {
    return executors;
  }

}
```

My IExecutorWrapper class has multiple implementations, each giving its own list of IExecutors. Only 1 is chosen at runtime, 
the logic to choose which implementation depends on a context. Whats the best way to design this such that my Driver class
doesn't need to change ? How will my GuiceModule look like ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is the logic behind the choice for the "IExecutorWrapper" ?

Comment: If ctx.contains("a") then choose 1 else choose the other.

Comment: you should be more specific. what is your context? where does it come from? who create/update it?

Comment: Context is more like a user input. It's created by the user and is something you get at runtime and is different for every request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom provider to achieve this, if a Manager is created for every request.

If `Context` is injectable (and maybe a request scoped service) :

```
@Provides
IExecutorWrapper createIExecutorWrapper(Context context) {
  if (context.isXX()) {
    return new Executor1();
  } else {
    return new Executor2();
  }
}
```

If the implementations of IExecutorWrapper should be injected by Guice, then you can annotated each implementation type, and inject the providers :

```
@Provides
IExecutorWrapper createIExecutorWrapper(Context context, 
       @Type1 Provider<IExecturoWrapper> type1, 
       @Type2 Provider<IExecutorWrapper> type2) {
  if (context.isXXX()) {
    return type1.get();
  } else {
    return type2.get();
  }
}
```

and the configuration:

```
bind(IExecutorWrapper.class).annotatedWith(Type1.class).to(Executor1.class);
bind(IExecutorWrapper.class).annotatedWith(Type2.class).to(Executor2.class);
```